# RadTreeView childnodes check if nodes already exist or not

Tags: telerik

currently, the rad tree view returning duplicate child nodes. How i can implement, to check if the childnode already exist or not. If already exist then do not add and continue looping. Thank you

private void BuildProjectTree()
    {

```
    EntityCollection<ProjectEntity> collection = GetProjectData();

    treProjects.Nodes.Clear();

    ArrayList pgnodes = new ArrayList();
    RadTreeNode pnode = null;
    RadTreeNode snode = null;
    //MembershipUserCollection membershipCollection = new MembershipUserCollection();
    //membershipCollection = Membership.GetAllUsers();


    foreach (ProjectEntity p in collection)
    {
        pnode = null;
        foreach (RadTreeNode n in treProjects.GetAllNodes())
        {
            //bool nodeExist = false;

                if (n.Text.Trim() == p.TeamLeader.Trim().ToUpper())
                {
                     pnode = n;
                     break;

                }



        }
        if (pnode != null)
        {
            snode = null;
            foreach (RadTreeNode n in pnode.Nodes)
            {


                if (n.Value == p.ProjectSubGroup.ProjectGroup.Name)
                {
                    snode = n;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (snode != null)
            {
                RadTreeNode projectnode = new RadTreeNode(p.ProjectTitle + " (" + p.ReferenceNumber + ")",
                                                          p.ProjectId.ToString(), BuildProjectNavigationUrl(p, false));

                snode.Nodes.Add(projectnode);
            }

        }
        else
        {

            RadTreeNode projectteamleadernode = new RadTreeNode(p.TeamLeader.Trim().ToUpper());

            RadTreeNode projectgroupnode = new RadTreeNode(p.ProjectSubGroup.ProjectGroup.Name, String.Empty);

            RadTreeNode projectnode = new RadTreeNode(p.ProjectTitle + " (" + p.ReferenceNumber + ")",
                                                     p.ProjectId.ToString(), BuildProjectNavigationUrl(p, false));






            projectgroupnode.Nodes.Add(projectnode);
            projectteamleadernode.Nodes.Add(projectgroupnode);


           pgnodes.Add(projectteamleadernode);

         }
    }

    foreach (RadTreeNode pg in pgnodes)
    {

        treProjects.Nodes.Add(pg);
    }
    //treProjects.ExpandAllNodes();
    treProjects.CollapseAllNodes();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fragment you provided should do what you're looking for. Initialize pnode to null prior to the loop and test pnode's value after the loop terminates.

If this does not help, please provide the code with which you are adding the nodes.

Comment: The only things that stick out are: `treProjects.Nodes.Clear();` Is this an artifact of your code sample? If not, you cannot clear the tree and then search for matches in it.  I also assume the tree is built with the team leader's name as upper-case. To be on the safe side add another upper in this line `if (n.Text.Trim().ToUpper() == p.TeamLeader.Trim().ToUpper())`